# Telerik Gantt Not Displaying Correctly with Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

I am using a Telerik Gantt chart to show a schedule of entries, contained in a bootstrap tab interface. I have a width/size issue.

When page is loaded, the Gantt chart width is not correct, but if I resize the window it corrects itself.

Here is how the Gantt appears when the page first loads:
[image]

After resizing the page, it fixes itself like so:

[image]

Here is my current code:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#steps" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Steps</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#schedule" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Schedule</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="steps">
    *other content*
    </div>
    <div role=tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="schedule">
       @(Html.Kendo()
                                .Gantt<RequestStepGanttViewModel, DependencyViewModel>((IEnumerable<RequestStepGanttViewModel>)ViewData["tasks"])
                                .Name("gantt")
                                .Columns(columns =>
                                {
                                    columns.Bound(c => c.TaskID).Title("ID").Width(50);
                                    columns.Bound("title").Editable(true).Sortable(true);
                                    columns.Bound("start").Title("Start Time").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Width(100).Editable(true).Sortable(true);
                                    columns.Bound("end").Title("End Time").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Width(100).Editable(true).Sortable(true);
                                })
                                .Views(views =>
                                {
                                    views.DayView();
                                    views.WeekView(weekView => weekView.Selected(true));
                                    views.MonthView();
                                })
                                .Editable(ed => ed.Destroy(false))
                                .Height(500)
                                .ShowPlannedTasks(false)
                                .ShowWorkHours(false)
                                .ShowWorkDays(false)
                                .DataSource(d => d
                                    .Model(m =>
                                    {
                                        m.Id(f => f.TaskID);
                                        m.ParentId(f => f.ParentID);
                                        m.OrderId(f => f.OrderId);
                                        m.Field(f => f.Expanded).DefaultValue(true);
                                    })
                                        .Destroy("Destroy_Task", "Orders")
                                        .Update(update => update.Action("Update_Task", "Orders").Data("onUpdateCreate"))
                                        .Create(create => create.Action("Create_Task", "Orders").Data("onUpdateCreate"))
                                )
                        )
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Probably the parent of the Gantt has wrong width when the Gantt initializes, so you may have a bit of a race condition in widget creation. Try a static width parent for the gantt to test (say, 500px wide div). You can also try deferring the kendo widget scripts hoping they will initialize late enough. Third idea, call the resize or repaint method of the Gantt with some small timeout after initialization

Comment: Yes, the small timeout is what I ended up using, I posted my solution below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing I found this solution the best:

I added an onclick event to the tab strip that calls the function below, and the function below waits 1 sec before refreshing/resizing the Gantt chart.

```
<script>
    function resizeGantt(){
        var delay = 1000;

        setTimeout(function () {
            var gantt = $("#gantt").data("kendoGantt");
            gantt.resize();
            gantt.refresh();
        }, delay);
       
    }       
</script>
```

Comment: Just .resize() should be enough